# Not able to connect mysql with python 2.7 in django 1.11 getting error while installing mysqlclient and MySQL-python both

Tags: python, mysql, django

i am trying to install mysql client to connect mysql with python 2.7 for django project but getting error, even i tried MySQL-python connector to install but getting error there also.

```
C:\Users\syedabdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dve
rsion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\pyt
hon27\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\syedabdul\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with
exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\syedab~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-xgy30p\\mysqlc
lient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))
" install --record c:\users\syedab~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-rs9dvc-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" fail
ed with error code 1 in c:\users\syedab~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-xgy30p\mysqlclient\
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the appropriate official python wheel for your system from pypi.python.org then install it by *pip install MySQLConnector2.7.whl* assuming MySQLConnector2.7.whl is the file name

Comment: how to install wheel?

Comment: i tried pip install wheel and wheel got installed but  MySQLConnector2.7.whl is not getting installed.

Comment: I don't know from what source you got the wheel because the official site the name is rarely that short. This is an official link to download *https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mysql#downloads* or *https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient* the wheel. Browse to the folder where you downloaded it via terminal or CMD and do *pip install filename.whl* Choose the appropriate one for your system of it fails try The others I'm confident you Will get a working one